# PHP script to convert Json to CSV

Tags: php, json, csv

I've got a API JSON service and need to create a script to export data to CSV files. 
Does anyone have a php script to migrate JSON to CSV format?

Example Json file

```
  {"packWidth":200,
  "itemNo":"SEH404",
  "groupItemNo":"SEH404",
  "status":1,
  "categoryId":24356,
  "packType":"ColorBox",
  "barcode":"1234567890987",
  "modelLabel":"Color",
  "modelList":[{"key":"SEH404","value":"Black"},{"key":"SEH404W","value":"White"}],
  "packQty":20,
  "packInclude":"USB Adapter, USB Charger, Earphone, Leather Case",
  "id":3456}
```

An important part is the array with the tag "modelList"

The result of the array modelList, must be a column for each value

example:

packWidth, itemNo, groupItemNo, status, categoryId, packType, barcode, modelLabel, modelList1, modelList2, packQty, packInclude, id

200, SEH404, SEH404, 1, 24356, ColorBox, 1234567890987, Color, **SEH404:Black, SEH404W:White**, 20, USB Adapter... , 3456

Some products may also contain 5 records "modelList1-modelList2 modelList3-modelList4-modelList5. Products without modelList will record modelList empty.

Comment: Use the built-in [json_decode($jsonString, true)](http://www.php.net/json_decode) function to convert that JSON string to an array, then iterate over it and output what you need.

Comment: How do you want to output the modelList ? for me it would be a whole string from "[{"key":"SEH404","value":"Black"},{"key":"SEH404W","value":"White"}]"

Comment: What do you want to do with modelList array? How to represent that data in CSV?

Comment: The result of the array modelList, must be a column for each value

example:

-----name columns-----packWidth, itemNo, groupItemNo, status, categoryId, packType, barcode, modelLabel, modelList1, modelList2, packQty, packInclude, id   -------value--------

200, SEH404, SEH404, 1, 24356, ColorBox, 1234567890987, Color, SEH404:Black, SEH404W:White, 20, USB Adapter... , 3456

Comment: @user3406254: ModelList will always contain 2 records to be joined with : in the modelList1 and modelList2 columns?

Comment: @user3406254: I am basically asking if modelList3, modelList4 might be required according to modelList record count. May be some modelList items have 2 records, some 3 and some more? What would you do in that case? In case this is the situation I would find the max modelList record count first then prepare the headers accordingly then fill in the records for the existing ones, leave blank for the short ones. Of course this is just assumption, if it will ALWAYS be 2 records, constant number, then it would be easier to handle.

Comment: Some products may also contain 5 records "modelList1-modelList2 modelList3-modelList4-modelList5. 
Products without modelList will record modelList empty.

Comment: Each column ModelList corresponds to an attribute for the product in the database.

Comment: @user3406254: I wrote a code that is supposed to produce desired CSV result for you. Please check it out.

Comment: Were you able to understand why it does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.
Assuming $json is the raw data, so I decoded it at the beginning.

```
$json = json_decode($json);

// Will use $csv to build our CSV content
$csv = array();

// Need to define the special column
$modelList = 'modelList';

// Find necessary additional column number for modelList
$maxSubData = 0;
foreach ($json as $id => $data)
{
    $maxSubData = max(array(count($data->modelList), $maxSubData ));
}

// Headers for CSV file
// Headers Start
$headers = array();
foreach ($json[0] as $key => $value)
{
    if ($key == $modelList)
    {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $maxSubData; $i++)
        {
            $headers[] = $modelList . $i;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $headers[] = $key;
    }
}
$csv[] = '"' . implode('","', $headers) . '"';
// Headers End

// Now the rows
// Rows Start
foreach ($json as $data)
{
    $fieldValues = array();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value )
    {
        if ($key == $modelList)
        {
            $j = 0;
            foreach ($value as $subValue)
            {
                $subData = array();
                foreach ($subValue as $subCols)
                {
                    $subData[] = $subCols;
                }
                $j++;
                $fieldValues[] = htmlspecialchars(implode(':', $subData ));
            }
            for ($i = $j + 1; $i <= $maxSubData; $i++)
            {
                $fieldValues[] = '';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $fieldValues[] = htmlspecialchars($value);
        }
    }

    $csv[] = '"' . implode('","', $fieldValues) . '"';
}
// Rows End

$finalCSV = implode("\n", $csv);

print $finalCSV;
```

Comment: With one product modelList works, but if i have many products in the json file, and the first is no record modelList does not work.

Comment: This is the original json file, I have tried but the script does not work well, and does not wrap. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/37k18vq538x5gio/json.txt

Comment: The posted code is the most simplified version of any possible solution for your initial question, by also expanding the initial question with possible requirements which were not originally provided. It can be adapted for the further requirements in your project. So I hope it gives a good start point like already mentioned as "works with on product" as it was asked in the question.
I hope it helps.

Comment: Hello, I thank you that I have provided aid. Surely it is a great script that I just have to adapt to my needs. 

Thanks again

Comment: I'm sorry, can I ask you one last question? 
To write values ​​to modelList in the last column of the csv file, to avoid confusion in the data, is it possible?  

Thanks in advance if you want me to respond

Comment: You can also use this function to simplify CSV file creating http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Answer (score -1):

It's impossible because in JSON You have hierarchical data structure, but CSV is only 2-dimensional (see modelList attribute).

Comment: This is the original json file, I have tried but the script does not work well, and does not wrap. dropbox.com/s/37k18vq538x5gio/json.txt

Comment: You can create a plain table using Iterators and creating nested keys for the csv heads

Comment: "Thanks" for down-vote, but still - plain table is plain table. It simply can't fully cover multi-level deep hierarchical structure which json can have.