# Why not all parameters from ambari cluster not represented by the blueprint json file

Tags: json, linux, hadoop, ambari

Why not all parameters from ambari cluster not represented by the blueprint json file ?

I generated the blueprint json file as the foolwing:

```
 curl -u admin:admin -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X GET http://10.23.4.122:8080/api/v1/clusters/HDP01?format=blueprint -o /tmp/HDP01_blueprint.json
```

but when I access to the ambari GUI we noticed that many parameters not appears in the blueprint json file

example of parameters from HDFS – config that not appears in the blueprint json file

```
DataNode failed disk tolerance

DataNode maximum Java heap size

DataNode max data transfer threads
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be seeing all parameters in output json file.

For few parameters Ambari GUI shows different names. 
Example:

DataNode failed disk tolerance - appears as dfs.datanode.failed.volumes.tolerated in ouput json

DataNode maximum Java heap size - appears as dtnode_heapsiz in ouput json

DataNode max data transfer threads - appears as dfs.datanode.max.transfer.threads in ouput json

Comment: first of all thank you so much , so how we can find each parameter from ambari GUI that is relevant to the json ( as you know we have more then 3000 parameters ) how we can handle this ?

Comment: btw - do you have chance to give me tip about my previous question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45688805/how-to-convert-blueprint-json-file-to-csv-file

Comment: @David, please accept answer if you are satisfied with it. 
About your question in comment- you will find parameter actual name and display name mapping in /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/common-services/<service>/<version>/configuration/<config file> e.g. /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/common-services/HDFS/2.1.0.2.0/configuration/hdfs-site.xml

Comment: under the folder we see only that - core-site.xml  hadoop-env.xml  hadoop-policy.xml  hdfs-log4j.xml  hdfs-logsearch-conf.xml  hdfs-site.xml  ssl-client.xml  ssl-server.xml    ( but I think we have alot of missing parameters that not defined on the xml above )

Comment: @David, I think you are referring /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/common-services/HDFS/2.1.0.‌​2.0/configuration directory , which will include only HDFS service related files. Please check configurations directory for other services such as HIVE, HBASE etc